# strftime: from where the locale (en, es...) is retrieved?

Tags: php

I have just found out the function `strftime()`. The manual says about it:

> Format a local time/date according to locale settings".

But...from where the locale (en, es...) is retrieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP will use the server's locale setting. You can set it via [setlocale()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php).